# Using SQLAlchemy to execute an SQL statement with named parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pg8000

Why can't I raw insert a list of dicts with SQLalchemy ?

```
import os
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd

def connect_unix_socket() -> sqlalchemy.engine:
    db_user = os.environ["DB_USER"]
    db_pass = os.environ["DB_PASS"]
    db_name = os.environ["DB_NAME"]
    unix_socket_path = os.environ["INSTANCE_UNIX_SOCKET"]
    return sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.create(
            drivername="postgresql+pg8000",
            username=db_user,
            password=db_pass,
            database=db_name,
            query={"unix_sock": f"{unix_socket_path}/.s.PGSQL.5432"},
        )
    )

def _insert_ecoproduct(df: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
    db = connect_unix_socket()
    db_matching = {
        'gtin': 'ecoproduct_id',
        'ITEM_NAME_AS_IN_MARKETPLACE' : 'ecoproductname',
        'ITEM_WEIGHT_WITH_PACKAGE_KG' : 'ecoproductweight',
        'ITEM_HEIGHT_CM' : 'ecoproductlength',
        'ITEM_WIDTH_CM' : 'ecoproductwidth',
        'test_gtin' : 'gtin_test',
        'batteryembedded' : 'batteryembedded'
    }
    df = df[db_matching.keys()]
    df.rename(columns=db_matching, inplace=True)
    data = df.to_dict(orient='records')
    sql_query = """INSERT INTO ecoproducts(
            ecoproduct_id,
            ecoproductname,
            ecoproductweight,
            ecoproductlength,
            ecoproductwidth,
            gtin_test,
            batteryembedded)
        VALUES (%(ecoproduct_id)s, %(ecoproductname)s,%(ecoproductweight)s,%(ecoproductlength)s,
            %(ecoproductwidth)s,%(gtin_test)s,%(batteryembedded)s) 
        ON CONFLICT(ecoproduct_id) DO NOTHING;"""

    with db.connect() as conn:
        result = conn.exec_driver_sql(sql_query, data)
        print(f"{result.rowcount} new rows were inserted.")
```

I keep having this error :
[image]

Is it possible to map parameters with th dialect pg8000 ? Or maybe I should use psycopg2 ?

What is the problem here ?

### EDIT 1: see variable data details :

```
print(data)
print(type(data))
[{'ecoproduct_id': '6941487202157', 'ecoproductname': 'HUAWEI FreeBuds Pro Bluetooth sans Fil ', 'ecoproductweight': '4', 'ecoproductlength': '0.220', 'ecoproductwidth': '0.99', 'gtin_test': False, 'batteryembedded': 0}]
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: can you please let me know what you get for the variable data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to map [named] parameters with th (sic) dialect pg8000 ?

Yes. Using a SQLAlchemy [text()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) object allows us to use named parameters even if the underlying DBAPI does not.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

sql_query = """\
INSERT INTO ecoproducts(
    ecoproduct_id,
    ecoproductname,
    ecoproductweight,
    ecoproductlength,
    ecoproductwidth,
    gtin_test,
    batteryembedded)
VALUES (
    :ecoproduct_id,
    :ecoproductname,
    :ecoproductweight,
    :ecoproductlength,
    :ecoproductwidth,
    :gtin_test,
    :batteryembedded) 
ON CONFLICT(ecoproduct_id) DO NOTHING;
"""
result = conn.execute(sa.text(sql_query), data)
```